Refresh problem for a large size table in Power BI Desktop and in Power BI Services
I have [WorkItems] tbl - 245 000 records, 90 MB original size - which is part of PBI Report.
It contains 30 API references (pulling data directly from API - 30 OData Feeds (Projects)).
Code written in PowerQuery (OData)
When I am refreshing this PBI report, the [WorkItems] table keeps failing with the following msg:

I was able to lower [WorkItems] tbl size by removing about half of the API calls (OData feeds) - left 12 out of 30.
Then the tbl size reduced to 42MB, and it's now about 100 000 records and refresh is 2 min
(3 min when I publish it on PBI Services; scheduled refresh is now not failing).
But - my problem - I need to keep ALL 30 OData Feeds (Projects)...
To achieve this:

Are there working and more or less quick ways to reduce this tbl size?

Should I add some sort of parameter(s) into Data Source settings - in order to speed up the refresh - to load my records in parts, quicker?

I added [Date] filter to reduce a tbl size - [Current Date] - 24 months. But it didn't reduced tbl size


Here is the code in OData, (I included only 3 out of 30 OData feeds):
Any suggestions would be very helpful
       // "$select=ParentWorkItemId, StoryPoints, State, 
WorkItemType, Title, IterationSK, AreaSK, WorkItemId" & "&$filter= 
(WorkItemType eq 'Bug' or WorkItemType eq 'User Story')", null, 
 [Implementation="2.0"]),

  let
      Source =      
     OData.Feed
     ("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/MyCompany/Research and 
                     Development/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?" & 
                     "$select=ParentWorkItemId, StoryPoints, 
                     State, 
                     WorkItemType, Title, IterationSK, AreaSK, 
                     WorkItemId, 
                     Area" & "&$filter=(WorkItemType eq 'Bug' or 
                     WorkItemType eq 'User Story')" & 
                     "&$expand=Area($select=AreaPath)", null, 
                     [Implementation="2.0"]),

      #"Add all Ops & CP projects" = Table.Combine({
      Source, 
   OData.Feed("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/MyCompany/Cloud 
               Platform/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?" & 
               "$select=ParentWorkItemId, StoryPoints, State, 
               WorkItemType, 
               Title, IterationSK, AreaSK, WorkItemId, Area" & 
               "&$filter= 
               (WorkItemType eq 'Bug' or WorkItemType eq 'User 
                Story')"  & 
               "&$expand=Area($select=AreaPath)", null, 
               [Implementation="2.0"]),

   OData.Feed("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/MyCompany/Batch 
              Management/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?" & 
              "$select=ParentWorkItemId, StoryPoints, State, 
              WorkItemType, 
              Title, IterationSK, AreaSK, WorkItemId, Area" & 
              "&$filter= 
              (WorkItemType eq 'Bug' or WorkItemType eq 'User 
               Story')"  & 
              "&$expand=Area($select=AreaPath)", null, 
              [Implementation="2.0"]),}),
  #"Add AreaPath" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Add all Ops & CP 
  projects", 
  "Area", {"AreaPath"}, {"AreaPath"}),

 // Calculate the date 24 months ago from the current date
    Date24MonthsAgo = Date.AddMonths(DateTime.LocalNow(), -24),

// Filter data to include only records from the last 24 months
   FilteredData = Table.SelectRows(ConvertedIDColumns, each 
   DateTime.From([CreatedDate]) >= Date24MonthsAgo),


  #"Rename Story Points to Effort" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Add 
    AreaPath", 
   {{"StoryPoints", "Effort"}}),
  #"Add Organization" = Table.AddColumn(#"Rename Story Points to 
   Effort", 
  "Organization", each "MyCompany"),
  #"Change IDs to text" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Add 
    Organization", 
   {{"WorkItemId",  type text}, {"ParentWorkItemId", type text}}),
  #"Make IDs unique" = Table.TransformColumns(
  #"Change IDs to text",
  {
    {
      "WorkItemId",
      each 
        Text.Combine({(_),"-VSTS"}),
      type text
    }
  }
),

#"Make Parent IDs unique" = Table.TransformColumns(
  #"Make IDs unique",
  {
    {
      "ParentWorkItemId",
      each 
        Text.Combine({(_),"-VSTS"}),
      type text
    }
  }
),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Make Parent IDs 
unique","-VSTS","",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"ParentWorkItemId"}),
#"Parent Orphans to ""No Feature""" = 
Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","","No 
Feature",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"ParentWorkItemId"})


 in
      #"Parent Orphans to ""No Feature"""


None of the 3 questions you ask will help with the root cause of the issue:
Are there working and more or less quick ways to reduce this tbl size?

Should I add some sort of parameter(s) into Data Source settings - in order to speed up the refresh - to load my records in parts, quicker?

I added [Date] filter to reduce a tbl size - [Current Date] - 24 months. But it didn't reduced tbl size

You're being throttled by the API's host. My suggestion would be to stagger your API requests using Function.InvokeAfter()
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/function-invokeafter

Thank you! I'll try and will text here about the outcome

Was this solved?
